# Populate null records scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table the following columns:

FirstName, LastName, Points, StartTime

I have the data right now with the StartTime populated for the person with the highest points. StartTime is Null for everyone else.

I want to do the following in a stored procedure:

Populate StartTime with intervals of 30 minutes. So right now there is only one person with StartTime. The next person in line in terms of points gets StartDate 30 minutes after the previous one. There are some conditions. Right now StartTime for the person with highest points is set to a working day and time is 8:00AM. The next one should be 8:30AM and so on. The last time for a working day is 5:00PM and then it should go to the next working day (skipping weekends) and continue assigning dates and times starting from 8:00AM to 5:00PM with 30 minutes increment - Only work days until all the StartTimes for all the rows are populated.
So there should be 18 people with a starttime for the same working day.
Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Which RDMS is this? (MySql, PostGres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Could you please provide the SQL you have so far?

Comment: At this point I am just gathering insights from other people. Getting ideas. It seems complicated and I don't know how or where to start. Also I am not an advanced SQL developer. I know the basics.

Comment: The easiest way would be be to loop over the data setting the highest Point person's start time and increment (with the weekend/end of day logic) the start time to the next available start time within the loop until there are no people left with a NULL starttime.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the fairly simple repeating pattern you can generate start times using some simple maths. Assuming a working week of Monday to Friday, this SQL will generate the available slot date/times;

```
declare @start_point datetime = '20180524 08:00' -- this MUST be a Monday date at 8am
declare @slot_duration int = 30 -- minutes
declare @slots_per_day int = 18
declare @slots_per_week int = @slots_per_day * 5

;with numbers as (select row_number() over (order by so1.object_id) - 1 as rn from sys.objects so1 cross join sys.objects so2)
select
    rn,
    rn / @slots_per_week as weeks, -- zero based number
    (rn % @slots_per_week) / @slots_per_day days, -- zero based number
    rn % @slots_per_day as slots, -- zero based number
    dateadd(minute, (rn % @slots_per_day) * @slot_duration,
            dateadd(day, (rn % @slots_per_week) / @slots_per_day,
                    dateadd(week, rn / @slots_per_week, @start_point)
                   )
    ) as StartTime
from
    numbers
order by rn
```

Now you can join to this data (subquery, temp table etc) to update your original table.

Comment: but the start date time can be any working day. It doesn't have to be Monday. It has to be any working day from 8 to 5. Will this work if the start date time is not Monday?

Comment: The maths used to generate the slot date/times requires @start_point datetime to be a Monday but you could handle a non-Monday start date for your schedule via the join used.